# Angular - How to bind a event to HTML elements by selector?

Tags: angular

I would like to bind a same event to all HTML elements that contains a specific class in a component

Example:

```
<span class="myClass">Item1</span>
<span class="myClass">Item2</span>
<span class="myClass">Item3</span>
```

What I would like to do in Angular 8+:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myClass").forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', event => myFunction(event));
```

Is this even possible with Angular?

I did some searches but I didn't find what I really need.

I need to do this inside a `MatTable` ng-containers that contains a `<span contentEditable=true></span>`

Answer (score 3):

If the elements will all share a common set of requirements (a certain class and listener), you could create a directive that encapsulates these and add that directive to the elements directly. Here's a [good article](https://medium.com/swlh/anatomy-of-angular-attribute-directive-selector-a1d83a73242) on Directive selector types (section 3 is about class selectors)

Regarding doing this automatically with a selector.... you're also trying to target elements that are in a `MatTable` `<span contenteditable..>`. I'm pretty sure that selectors in Angular directives cannot *cross element boundaries* e.g. cannot target child elements of a particular matching element. You may need to go with your `querySelectorAll` approach on this one

Although it's considered **bad practice** to revert to using `querySelector` in Angular, **the Angular team do it themselves when needs be**:

- [Angular Material Table](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/table/sticky-styler.ts#L164)
- [Angular Material - Google Maps Component](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/google-map/google-map.ts#L266)
- [Angular CDK - Drag and Drop](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2240b4496e1621ff7fdad2935945ccad67ccc8b6/src/cdk/drag-drop/clone-node.ts)

**Note**: when you try to remove the components that have the listeners attached, they may linger in memory if the component with the event handlers is still around - so remove the listeners if that's the case.... or not